# Get total file size of all specified folders recursively

Tags: linux, centos, bash

I'm using `svn` on a project and I'm trying to see how much file space all of the `.svn` folders are taking up.

If I do something like

```
du -h | egrep ".*\.svn$"
```

It will list all of the `.svn` folders and their sizes, but on 3k+ lines. How can I total all these lines (or perform an operation that would give me the equivalent result)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
du -shc `find . -name .svn -print`
```

`-print` can be omitted if you are using `find` from GNU coreutils.

Comment: Did the trick. Didn't know about the `-c` option. Thanks.